# Why is part of my output not being displayed when I print it?

Tags: java

What I was doing was when I type in a name of guitar, it would show some specs such as shape of the body, number of frets, etc.

so I created a main coding class

```
package Guitar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Input name of the guitar");

        Scanner name_g = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name_gf = name_g.next();

        Gibson g = new Gibson();

        System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : ");
        g.body_shape(name_gf);

        System.out.println("Number of frets of the Guitar is : ");
        g.num_frets(name_gf);

        System.out.println("Neck type of the guitar is : ");
        g.neck_type(name_gf);

        System.out.println("Pickup configuration of the guitar is : ");
        g.pup_conf(name_gf);


    }

}
```

and another class specific for Gibson guitar

```
package Guitar;

public class Gibson extends SpecsVar implements SpecsInterface  {




    @Override
    public String body_shape(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Body shape of the guitar is : ");

        if (input.equals(lp)){ 
            return lp;}
        else if (input.equals(ex)){
            return ex;}
        else if (input.equals(sg)){
            return sg;}
        else return "invalid Input.";


    }

    @Override
    public String num_frets(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (input.equals(lp)){ 
            return shrt_fret;}
        else if (input.equals(ex)){
            return shrt_fret;}
        else if (input.equals(sg)){
            return shrt_fret;}
        else return "";

    }

    @Override
    public String neck_type(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (input.equals(lp)){ 
            return mh;}
        else if (input.equals(ex)){
            return rw;}
        else if (input.equals(sg)){
            return rw;}
        else return "";

    }

    @Override
    public String pup_conf(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (input.equals(lp)){ 
            return hh;}
        else if (input.equals(ex)){
            return hh;}
        else if (input.equals(sg)){
            return hh;}
        else return "";

    }

}
```

Then I had specs class

```
package Guitar;

public class SpecsVar {

    //Body Shape
    String lp = "Les Paul";
    String ex = "Explorer";
    String sg = "SG";

    //Number of Frets
    String shrt_fret = "22";
    String lng_fret = "24";

    //Neck Type
    String rw = "Rosewood";
    String mp = "Maple";
    String mh = "Mahogany";

    //Pickup Configuration
    String hsh = "HSH";
    String sss = "SSS";
    String hss = "HSS";
    String hh = "HH";

}
```

Then an interface

```
package Guitar;

public interface SpecsInterface {

    String body_shape(String input);

    String num_frets(String input);

    String neck_type(String input);

    String pup_conf(String input);

}
```

What happening is that it shows

```
Input name of the guitar
Gibson
Body Shape of the Guitar is : 
Body shape of the guitar is : 
Number of frets of the Guitar is : 
Neck type of the guitar is : 
Pickup configuration of the guitar is :
```

when I run it but it doesn't show the number of frets, shape of body, etc.

Comment: thats a hell lot of code for some one started learning code yesterday

Comment: If you started coding yesterday then you right on time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: This type of question is wrong on here. You need to already know you problem and then ask for a solution, we are not for debugging your code if you have no clue what's wrong with it.

Comment: Oh ok sorry guys I had no idea. So where would I post in the future for help if I had similar problem?

Comment: Ok I don't know where to put like an overall comment but thank you guys for all your help !!

Comment: @user5666063 *So where would I post in the future for help if I had similar problem?* Here, but before doing so, read [How to make a runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), once done, you'll know what to do and how, before asking. *Ok I don't know where to put like an overall comment* Well instead of an overall comment, [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped you solving your problem.

Comment: @user5666063 Just upvote things that are helpful and mark your favourite solution as the answer. That's how the karma thing works on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `System.out.println()` you're doing this:

```
System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : ");
g.body_shape(name_gf);
```

Simply move `g.body_shape(name_gf);` into your `System.out.println()` calls and do the same for all the rest of them. This is called [String concatenation](http://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java)

```
System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : " + g.body_shape(name_gf));
```

This happens because the `System.out.println()` is what actually prints on screen, but your second part `g.body_shape(name_gf);` was only doing a search but nothing else, so that's why you just had to put it into your print call.

Answer (score 2):

Change your main to look like this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Input name of the guitar");

    Scanner name_g = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name_gf = name_g.next();

    Gibson g = new Gibson();

    System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : " + g.body_shape(name_gf));


    System.out.println("Number of frets of the Guitar is : " + g.num_frets(name_gf));


    System.out.println("Neck type of the guitar is : " + g.neck_type(name_gf));


    System.out.println("Pickup configuration of the guitar is : " + g.pup_conf(name_gf));



  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : ");
g.body_shape(name_gf);
```

The first line is printing out a partial message, but the second isn't. That second line just gets a value from the guitar, it doesn't display it.  Concatenate that value on to the end of the message like this:

```
System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : " + g.body_shape(name_gf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well those variables aren't being printed out BECAUSE they aren't inside of the print statement. You just need to move lines like `g.body_shape(name_gf);` to be included inside your print statement like so `System.out.println("Body Shape of the Guitar is : " + g.body_shape(name_gf));`